# Use SPServices UpdateListItems to set date in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I cannot find a working solution to set a SharePoint 2013 list date using SPServices.  I have done this multiple times for other column types, but I can't figure out the right format for dates.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
var testdate = "2016-01-01 00:00:00";
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    ID: 4,
    valuepairs: [["Due Date", testdate]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    }
});
```

I have also tried it with these test values, but nothing changes on my site:

```
var testdate = "2016-1-1 0:0:0";
var testdate = "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z";
var testdate = "2016-1-1T0:0:0Z";
var testdate = "2016-01-01T00:00:00";
var testdate = "2016-1-1T0:0:0";
```

Please let me know if there's another date format I should try, or if you see anything else wrong with this code.  It works when I point to one of my text fields, so I'm pretty sure it's just the date format that's messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UpdateListItems` operation expects date string to be provided in [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), for example:

```
var dueDateVal = new Date('2016-01-01 6:00:00').toISOString();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    ID: 1,
    valuepairs: [["DueDate", dueDateVal]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         console.log('List items has been updated');
    }
});
```

---

In addition, make sure the *proper name* of `Due Date` column is specified. `UpdateListItems` operation expects an array of column [StaticNames](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Glossary&referringTitle=UpdateListItems&ANCHOR#StaticName) and values have to be specified for `valuepairs`.

If column named `Due Date` has been created via UI, then `Due_x0020_Date` static name will be generated and the operation for setting its value the should be specified like this:

```
var dueDateVal = new Date('2016-01-01 6:00:00').toISOString();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    ID: 1,
    valuepairs: [["Due_x0020_Date", dueDateVal]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         console.log('List items has been updated');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!  The toISOString() was exactly what I needed.  The only thing I had to change was the way you entered the date in new Date().  This is what worked for me: `var dueDateVal = new Date(2016,00,01).toISOString();`